# jquery plugin, settimeout and div not being append, simple weird case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jquery plugin the code below is not working (I mean the setTimeout is working but nothing is append)

```
var self = this;
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.append(bubble);
    }, 1000);
}
```

And the code below is working:

```
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    this.append(bubble);
}
```

***this*** is a jquery selection. I really don't get what's going on. It can't be scope issue .. can it be ? I don't get it. Thanks in advance for you help

Edit: bubble is a simple div (" ")

Below the whole plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.randomBubble = function(options) {
        var self = this;
        var settings = $.extend({
            color: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            maxBubbleSize: 100
        }, options);

        var frame = {
            height: this.height(),
            width: this.width(),
        }

        var bubble = "<div class='randomBubble'> </div>";


        this.getLeft = function(width) {
            var left = Math.random() * frame.width;
            if (left > (frame.width / 2)) {
                left -= width;
            } else {
                left += width;
            }
            return left
        }

        this.getTop = function(height) {
            var top = Math.random() * frame.height;
            if (top > (frame.height / 2)) {
                top -= height;
            } else {
                top += height;
            }
            return top
        }


        this.removeBubbles = function() {
            var currentBubbles = this.find('.randomBubble');
            if (currentBubbles.length) {
                currentBubbles.remove();
            }
        }

        window.oh = this;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            var timer = Math.random() * 1000;
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.uh = self;
                self.append(bubble);
                console.log("oh");
            }, 1000);
        }

        this.randomize = function() {
            //self.removeBubbles();
            var allBubbles = this.find('.randomBubble');

            allBubbles.each(function(i, el) {
                var height = Math.random() * settings.maxBubbleSize;
                var width = height;
                $(el).css({
                    color: settings.color,
                    backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor,
                    zIndex: 1000,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    borderRadius: '50%',
                    top: self.getTop(height),
                    left: self.getLeft(width),
                    height: height,
                    width: width
                });

            });
        }
        this.randomize();
        //var run = setInterval(self.randomize, 4000);

        return this.find('.randomBubble');
    }


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the bubbles are appended later due to the `setTimeout()`, this selector in your `randomize()` function comes up empty:

```
var allBubbles =  this.find('.randomBubble');
```

That is why appending them in a simple for loop works fine.

If you really want to use the `setTimout()` to append your bubbles, one option is to style them when you add them:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var height = Math.random() * settings.maxBubbleSize;
    var width = height;
    var b = $(bubble).css({
        color: settings.color,
        backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor,
        zIndex: 1000,
        position: 'absolute',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        top: self.getTop(height),
        left: self.getLeft(width) ,
        height: height,
        width: width
    });
    self.append(b);
}, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egsqrL8h/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you still call randomize() right away, even when you postpone the creation for one second?

You will also return an empty selection in that case, for the same reason.

Also, you probably want to **use** the timer variable in setTimeout() instead of hardcoding all to 1000 ms?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a javascript selection, the selector in jquery is `$(this)`

```
$.fn.randomBubble = function(options) {
    var self = $(this);
};
```